# Can two users connected to a DB and update the same row of a table simultaneously in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can two users connected to a DB and update the same row of a table simultaneously in SQL server?

For example, user A and user B are logged in to a same DB simultaneously and begin new transactions and then update a weekly rent simultaneously.

The original weekly rent is $300/pw.

User A: Update RENT Set WeeklyRent = WeeklyRent* 1.1 where Address ='121 Green'

User B: Update RENT Set WeeklyRent = WeeklyRent* 1.2 where Address ='121 Green'

Then User A issues a Commit statement.
Then User B issues a Commit statement.

What will be the final rent price? Will this be $330 or $360 or $300? 
I've researched it and it seems like the data won't change because of 'deadlock'. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance~

Comment: Did you try? Why not?

Comment: I would try if I could do update simultaneously. I only have one computer.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server will lock the table/row/page to ensure that you will be able to do the update. However we are talking milliseconds in most cases so it is almost impossible for them to be "simultaneously" updating the same record. Just be sure to always use a transaction and limit connection times because the record will be locked until the transaction ends.

Comment: Thanks Russell, so the answer to the question would be $300? yeah, I also think 'simultaneously' is not really possible but this was a given condition so I just had to answer to the question... I answered it $300. I hope this is correct...

Comment: Not necessarily. As @ta.speot.is pointed out, there are a number of factors that could come into play. If this was a question on an exam, I would ask the instructor to explain how he came to that conclusion and then post back for us to comment. There are a lot of unknowns in your question.

Comment: Right, but this exam is online exam so no instructor to ask.... the question I've posted is exactly the same (maybe I missed out some words but the meaning is the same) as the question I had on the exam. uhmmm.... so this question has lot of unknowns.... but if you were me, what would you have answered? Thanks anyway Russell~

Comment: Well the question states that User A commits, THEN user B commits, which would make you think that user B results were updated LAST. However, if they were trying to update at the same time, then User A would have had a lock on the record nullifying User B's update. As I said, you'd need more information to be certain about this particular scenario. In any case, I'd question the examiner if they marked me wrong on this question.